# Unable to authenticate a user in Laravel: 'invalid username or password'

Tags: php, laravel

I have the username and password passed via a post request from my view to the controller. The controller responsible for handling the post request:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (!Auth::attempt([
            'username' => $request['username'],                    
            'password' => $request['password'] ])) { 
            return redirect()->back()->with(['fail' => 'invalid username or password']);      
        }

        return redirect()->route('auth.dashboard');                            
    }
```

The problem is I keep getting 'fail' message: 'invalid username or password'.

I looked at the table inside the phpmyadmin, and the username and password were pretty simple (username: Admin & password: 12345).

This is the database for the admins table :

```
class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('admins');
    }
}
```

For reference, I am using Laravel 5.2

**update 1**: The users are created via the registration controller, which stores the username and password in the database. Here is the controller:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request) {

        $admin = new Admin();

        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|unique:admins|max:30|min:3',
            'password' => 'required|min:5',
            'password_confirm' => 'required'           
        ]);

        $password = $request['password'];
        $passwordConfirm = $request['password_confirm'];

        if ($password !== $passwordConfirm) {
            return redirect()->back()->with(['fail' => 'password fields do not match!']);
        }     
        $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $admin->username = $request['username'];
        $admin->password = $hashedPassword;
        $admin->save();

        return redirect()->route('index')->with(['success' => 'Successfully created account!']);       

    }
```

Comment: i prefer using Hash::make instead of password_hash. because there's an additional option in Hash::make that was passed to password_hash. Thats why the hashing didnt matched

Comment: That fixed it! Please type this as an answer so I can upvote and tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i prefer using Hash::make instead of password_hash. because there's an additional option in Hash::make that was passed to password_hash. Thats why the hashing didnt matched

Comment: Cheers! That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

your always getting false in Auth::attempt because the password in your database in not hash. Hash your password in your database first. You could use the seeder in order to seed in the database

```
class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
       //your admin model
       Admin::create([
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => Hash::make(123)
       ]);
     }
}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: I am hashing the passwords in light of Bruce's comment. Please see the update above!

Comment: Also, I dont want to use a Seeder because I want to be able to let users signup, however, when I try the code above, it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please change login function with following code.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt([
            'username' => $request['username'],                    
            'password' => $request['password'] ],$remember)) { 
            return redirect()->route('auth.dashboard');            
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with(['fail' => 'invalid username or password']);

    }
```

Note : Here `$remember` should be a 1/0 or TRUE/FALSE.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I copy pasted your code, I got the error "undefined variable remember", then I set it to true and passed it to the attempt method, and I got the same error as before.

Comment: @Frosty619 Make sure your password in database is what, Means in which format? Laravel use hash function for storing password in database. And still you will get same error then store hash value in password column in database and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel will expect hashed passwords. 
So if the password in phpmyadmin is visible, it won't work be able to be verified in Laravel. I would expect the password in phpmyadmin to look like this `$2y$13$Cn0gwiUfg2mq5Y3/V98aB.NZ4GJqjbwhvKlsSAOYkVNHKlWRmwZ1W`

Comment: In light of your comment, I added the password_hash method in my registration controller. I created a new admin whose password is stored as a hashed string in phpmyadmin, but I am still getting the same error. Please see the update for more information. Thankyou!

Comment: Try the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35884495/21460 as I only have a surface knowledge of laravel

Comment: No worries, thank you for the help! I am not interested in using a Seeder because I want users to be able to register.